# Reset a div after its been faded in to prevent 'stacking'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this which shows a scroll to top button.

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $("#totop").fadeIn();
} else {
    $("#totop").stop().fadeOut();
}
```

This div has a opacity of 0.8, If i repeat the scroll up and down motion the div slowly fades out as im guessing it becomes 0.8 of 0.8 and then 0.8 of that opacity etc.

How can i stop this happening?

Comment: add html and css here, better to make http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Please re-explain what you want to stop?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [fadeTo](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/) for handling opacity:

try this:

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $("#totop").fadeTo( "slow", 0.8 );
} else {
    $("#totop").stop().fadeTo( "slow", 0);
}
```